# Merge where some ids are concatenated in single column

Tags: r, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe with a column of ids, but for some rows there are multiple ids concatenated together. I want to merge this onto another dataframe using the id, and when the ids are concatenated it handles that and reflects it by having the values in the new columns added also concatenated.

For example I have dataframes

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 4, 3, "2,3", "1,4"),
    value = c(1:5)
)
> data
   id value
1   1     1
2   4     2
3   3     3
4 2,3     4
5 1,4     5

mapping <- data.frame(
    id = 1:4,
    name = c("one", "two", "three", "four")
)
> mapping
  id  name
1  1   one
2  2   two
3  3 three
4  4  four
```

I would like to end up with

```
   id value      name
1   1     1       one
2   4     2      four
3   3     3     three
4 2,3     4 two,three
5 1,4     5  one,four
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do this other than to separate, join, and re-concatenate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(true_id = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(id, convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(mapping, by = "id") %>%
  group_by(true_id, value) %>%
  summarize(id = toString(id), name = toString(name), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   true_id value id    name      
#     <int> <int> <chr> <chr>     
# 1       1     1 1     one       
# 2       2     2 4     four      
# 3       3     3 3     three     
# 4       4     4 2, 3  two, three
# 5       5     5 1, 4  one, four
```

I wasn't sure if your `value` column would actually be unique, so I added a `true_id` just in case.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this. I could think of a few ways. One is longer, but much easier to follow and the other is short, but kind of a mess.

```r
library(tidyverse)


#long and readable
data |>
  mutate(tmp = row_number()) |>
  mutate(id = str_split(id, ",")) |>
  unnest_longer(id) |>
  left_join(mapping |>
              mutate(id = as.character(id)), by = "id") |>
  group_by(tmp) |>
  summarise(id = paste(id, collapse = ","),
            value = value[1],
            name = paste(name, collapse = ","))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     tmp id    value name     
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <chr>    
#> 1     1 1         1 one      
#> 2     2 4         2 four     
#> 3     3 3         3 three    
#> 4     4 2,3       4 two,three
#> 5     5 1,4       5 one,four


#short and ugly
data |>
  mutate(name = map_chr(id, \(x)paste(
    mapping$name[which(as.character(mapping$id) %in% str_split(x, ",")[[1]])], 
    collapse = ",") ))
#>    id value      name
#> 1   1     1       one
#> 2   4     2      four
#> 3   3     3     three
#> 4 2,3     4 two,three
#> 5 1,4     5  one,four
```

Comment: The short and ugly solution may also be efficient and clever--I'd lead with that.

Answer (score 1):

`grep`ing the `data$id`s out of the `mapping$id`s.

```
mapply(\(x, y) toString(mapping$name[grep(sprintf('[%s]', gsub('\\D', '', x)), y)]), 
       data$id, list(mapping$id))
#     1            4            3          2,3          1,4 
# "one"       "four"      "three" "two, three"  "one, four"
```

In order not to have a space after the comma, use `paste(., collapse=',')` instead of `toString`.